# Duplicating a cloth without rebaking?

Tags: physics

I'm messing around with physics simulation (it is so frustrating) and I have a question. I have a flag waving around (baked) and I want to duplicate that flag, so I can have different country flags waving around in the same way as each other, but I still haven't figured out how to do that. Is there a way to save the baked simulation as some kind of file and import it to other meshes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Export the animation as .mdd file (enable export mdd addon in preferences). Choose the right fps and start and end frame of animation.
2. Now you can delete the cloth modifier from your flag object and delete all caches.
3. Add a *Mesh Cache* modifier to your flag and load the .mdd file with your animation.
4. Add a material slot and change it's link from *Data* to *Object*. Your flag copies will share the same mesh but will be able to have different materials.
5. Duplicate your flags with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. The *Mesh Cache* modifier will be copied to all the flags also.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the technique outlined at http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-212710.html?s=fc9dd18317cca20fab0669fd2eb76dff where you go frame by frame and save the sim results as a shape key.  Making all the duplicates and unifying them onto the target mesh are probably the trickiest bits.

Looping cloth sims is also super hard.  You might want to come up with a procedural loop as shape keys using python, but that could take a veteran an entire afternoon to code.